# How do I access this variable in react js?

Tags: reactjs

Parent Component:

```
render(){
    console.log("here2");
    var temp = [];
    this.props.datarows.forEach((data, key) => {
            temp = this.props.datarows[key]  })
    return(
            <tr>
                <ListColumn col = { this.temp } />
            </tr>
        )
}
```

ListColumn.py

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default class ListColumn extends Component{

    render(){
        var columns = [];
        console.log("here3")
        console.log(this.props.col);
        // for (var key in this.props.col)
        // {
        //  columns.push(<td>this.props.col[key]</td>)
        // }
        // console.log(columns);
        // return(
        //  columns
        // )
        return(
                <td>a</td>
            )
    }
}
```

When I tried printing the value of `this.props.col`, it returns `undefined`, How do I access the variable temp? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`<ListColumn col = { this.temp } />`

use

`<ListColumn col = {temp } />`

**Reason**: In JS `this` refers to the object that own the code, inside render method `this` will refer to the react component. If you use this.temp, it will not take the local variable (defined inside render method), So instead of this.temp use temp (local variable).

One more thing, if you use it like this:

```
this.props.datarows.forEach((data, key) => {
         temp = this.props.datarows[key]  })
```

temp will have the last value of `this.props.datarows` array. I think, you want something like this:

```
this.props.datarows.forEach((data, key) => {
      if(/*use some condition to filter out the value that you want to save in temp array*/){
           temp.push(data);
      }
}
```

or if you want to assign the same `array` to temp variable, `looping` is not required in that case.

**Suggestion**: In place of `this.props.datarows[key]` you can use `data` also, because `data` and `this.props.datarows[key]` will be same.

Comment: https://medium.com/@rajwar67/a-guide-to-bind-this-keyword-in-react-js-256c7ee39970#:~:text=Since%20React%20is%20a%20javascript,current%20execution%20context%20in%20javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is,temp decalared as `var temp = [];` but you passing `this.temp`
change:  `<ListColumn col = { this.temp } />`

to

```
<ListColumn col ={temp } />
```

So,

```
render(){
    console.log("here2");
    var temp = [];
    this.props.datarows.forEach((data, key) => {
            temp = this.props.datarows[key]  })//it should be temp.push(data) if you want to pass all datarows as props
    return(
            <tr>
                <ListColumn col = {temp } />
            </tr>
        )
}
```

2.

```
 for (var key in this.props.col)
    {
      columns.push(<td>this.props.col[key]</td>)
     }
```

Should be

```
 for (var key in this.props.col)
     {
        columns.push(<td key={key}>{this.props.col[key]}</td>)
     }
```